# How can I increase the height for a specific Cell in a specific Section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

How can I increase the height for a specific cell (in a UITableView) at a specific Section (second section in my case where is that image with Swift).
I don't know if is possible to set my cell to be resized automatically but all what I want for the moment is to increase the size for that cell because I can't see anything inside.
My app is looking like this:
[image: Cell is too small]

I want to increase the size for that cell where is a WebView inside.

Here is my code:

```
extension DetailsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        switch section {
        case 0: return 6
        case 1: return 1
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch indexPath.section{
        // Section 1: Repository Details
        case 0:

            let cell = detailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "repoDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsTableViewCell

            // Set each row from first section
            switch indexPath.row{

            case 0:

                cell.avatarImageView.downloadedFrom(link: "\(selectedRepo.owner.avatarURL)")

                if indexPath.row == 0{
                    self.detailsTableView.rowHeight = 60
                }

                cell.textLabel?.isHidden = true
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = selectedRepo.description
                cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
                cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
                return cell
            case 1:
                cell.textLabel?.text = selectedRepo.description
                cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
                cell.detailTextLabel?.isHidden = true
                return cell
            case 2:
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Open Issues"
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(selectedRepo.openIssuesCount)
                return cell
            case 3:
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Forks"
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(selectedRepo.forksCount)
                return cell
            case 4:
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Watchers"
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(selectedRepo.watchersCount)
                return cell
            case 5:
                cell.textLabel?.text = "URL"
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = selectedRepo.htmlURL
                cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blue
                cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
                return cell
            default:
                return cell

            }

        // Section 2: Webview
        case 1:

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "repoWebviewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsTableViewCell

            // Set the WebView from Section 2
            switch indexPath.row{
            case 0:

                UIWebView.loadRequest(cell.webView)(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "\(selectedRepo.htmlURL)/blob/master/README.md")! as URL) as URLRequest)


                return cell
            default:
                return cell
            }

        default: return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the `heightForRowAt` delegate method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == someSection && indexPath.row == someRow {
        return someBiggerHeight
    } else {
        return tableView.rowHeight // return the standard height for all others
    }
}
```

If you need to check multiple index paths then using a `switch` is easier:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath {
    case [someSection, someRow]:
        return someBiggerHeight
    case [someOtherSection, someOtherRow]:
        return someOtherBiggerHeight
    default:
        return tableView.rowHeight // return the standard height for all others
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, as usual. (Voted.) To the OP: Be aware that there is a performance cost to implementing the `heightForRowAt` delegate method. The table view has to do a lot more work to calculate scroll positions when your cell has variable-height cells. You should think seriously about also setting the `estimatedRowHeight` property on your table view if you have a custom implementation of `heightForRowAt`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `heightForRow` delegate method and return appropriate height for the row of that section. If you need variable heights for different rows of different sections then you can use switch on tableview section and row and return different values.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
     case (1, 0):
         return 200
     case (0, _):
         return 60
     default: 
         return 60 //some default value
    }
}
```